# Clearing the application cache for websites that you "Add to your Home screen" on the iPad

Tags: ipad, safari, webkit

**The Problem:** I have tried just about everything I can think of to clear the cache of a website that has been added to my home screen. Here is what I have tried.

1. Close all running instances of the webapp by double clicking the home screen.
2. Closed all instances of Safari.
3. Removed the webapp from the Home Screen.
4. Settings -> Safari -> Cleared Cache and History.

In Safari, the cache is all cleared and I see the latest version of my web app. However, Once I add it to the home screen, it will display the old version. If i append a '#' to the url it will load only the new html file, however it looks like all the css includes are still cached.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: This drives me nuts! I tried to debug a video page, fullscreen view was buggy. All other browsers and devices were fixed, but iPads' Safari kept the error. When I realized that refreshing & clearing the cahce doesn't help, but changing to another URL, I already wasted 2 hours of my work day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a cache manifest file, make sure to change something in the .manifest file to trigger a cache refresh.

Comment: Didn't work for me on iPad Mini.  Followed instructions here...
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Comment: This will only work if you own the website and can modify the manifest file

Answer (score 10):

Set the date of your iPad several days to the future and reopen the web app. It then reloads it correctly. After that, you can reset the date to the current date.
Very odd, Apple should care about that...

Comment: Much simpler answer. Worked. +1

Comment: Works for me on iPad Mini, iOS 6!

Comment: Useless in production

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the subdirectory of the URL being bookmarked (e.g. change www.mysite.com/test1 to www.mysite.com/test2) and then re-add the site to the home screen that should work too.

Answer (score 0):

After using the date trick mentioned by Lukas, add some meta tags to the `<head>` section of your html to make sure it reloads easily in the future:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```